# LaunchSettings,json pass two arguments to startup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to have the syntax for passing two arguments in the launchsettings.json

"commandLineArgs": "arg1","arg2"

I know this syntax is wrong, what is the proper method?

I tried the following:

"commandLineArgs": "arg1,arg2"     but this passes only one argument

"commandLineArgs": "arg1","arg2"   but creates an invalid json

Comment: Have you tried separating args by a space? This is normally how I'd pass-in args to a CLI command `"commandLineArgs": "arg1 arg2"`.
Normally in JSON we'd create an array for multiple items e.g., `"key": ["val1","val2"]` but this may or may not be appropriate for your case. You may also want to try using a JSON validator like https://jsonlint.com/ to check for syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

"commandLineArgs": "---args1 val1 ---args2 val2",
"environmentVariables": ...

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?