# Is there a way to pass argument to launchSettings.json in .NET?

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, arguments, command-line-interface

I'm using .NET 7 and I have the `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5219;http://10.17.40.77:5219;"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to change the "applicationUrl" tag by cli when I build the .NET application. Something like: `dotnet publish ... --applicationUrl="http://10.17.30.11:5000;, http://11.22.33.44:1000;`. Is this possible?
I didn't found anything about it other than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75161104/launchsettings-json-pass-two-arguments-to-startup).

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You might be able to set these values in a pre- or post build event. Instead of launchsettings you could also get these settings from code or configuration files where you can differenciate between different environments (development / production)

Comment: First of all `launchSettings.json` has nothing to do with publish it is not published and is used only for development environments.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a .NET application, the launchSettings.json file is typically used to configure settings for launching and debugging your application in Visual Studio. This file is not designed to accept command-line arguments directly. However, you can achieve similar functionality by modifying your application code to handle command-line arguments.

In your application code, you can access command-line arguments using the Environment.GetCommandLineArgs method.

Comment: did you generate this with AI too like [your other AI answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501559/11107541)?